# Is using SAStid soap good for eczema skin?

Tags: dermatology, eczema, soap, drug-withdrawal

I have eczema, and after knowing that I'm addicted to steroid drug, I decide to withdraw it and have many [symptoms after discontinue using steroids](http://itsan.org/what-is-rss/), including **flaking skin**, irritated, infected, or reddened on skin. I go to an immunologist, and he prescribes me a SAStid bar for my eczema skin. He says that it will strip out all of my skin flakes.

[image]

It works. However my skin is very dry afterward. I search the side effect of the SAStid soap:

> Sastid Soap may cause the following symptoms that are **related to
>   eczema** (inflamed, red, itchy, scaking skin rash with sores and
>   crusting):
>
> ```
>  Red/inflammed rash.
>  Reddening of the skin due to widening of small blood vessels (uncommon)
>  Shedding of skin (uncommon)
>  Skin disorders (uncommon)
>  Skin redness (uncommon)
> ```
>
> Source: [DoubleCheckMD](http://doublecheckmd.com/EffectsDetail.do?dname=Sastid%20Soap&sid=10637&eid=3110)

Even [Drug.com](http://www.drugs.com/cdi/sastid-soap.html) recommends that:

> Do not use SAStid soap on skin that is irritated, infected, or reddened.

**Q**: I see many reviews that this product does what it supposes to do, but under my condition, I don't know if this prescription is good or not. **Is using SAStid soap good for eczema skin?** (Especially during steroid withdrawal.)

[image]

Comment: Did he recommend a lotion to use after using the soap?  I have a similar situation.  The dermatologist recommended Cetaphil Restoraderm Eczema Calming Body Moisturizer immediately after bath/shower.

Comment: Yes, but it just helped a little. After I complained about this, he stopped

Answer (score 2):

It seems that SAStid contains salicylic acid. Salicylic acid a keratolytic: it helps to peel the outer layers of the thick skin [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratolytic). As so it is helpful in the treatment of warts and psoriasis [(2)](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1943419-treatment#d9).

With eczema there is no skin thickening or dandruff. So I see no real benefits with that soap. It is obvious that when the outermost layer of your skin is peeled off it increases the loss of humidity from skin resulting to dryness. Since the most common problem with eczema is the dryness of the skin it only makes it worse [(3)](http://nationaleczema.org/eczema/treatment/bathing/taking-care-of-dry-skin/).

Comment: well, actually during topical steroid withdrawal, the skin actually flake. See my update.